# Page numbers in contents and footer

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

I've been trying to work out how to make page numbers skip the first two pages (title page and contents), and also how to have the footer say "page x of y", rather than just the current page which insert->header & footer->page number provides.

I found out how to split the document into 3 sections (title,contents, and the main document), and how to use "Format Page Numbers" to offset the numbers by 2, which seems to work as long as I don't insert another page at the start before the main section (eg the contents runs onto a  second page), however this doesn't solve the total page number problem, and doesn't seem a very clean solution since it relies on me entering the correct page offset...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

and use **{ SECTIONPAGES }** to insert the total number of pages in a section.

Answer (score 1):

What option are you choosing under Insert > Header & Footer > Page Number?

For all of the options except for "Page Margins" there are "Page X of Y" options - You may have to scroll down a bit to see them.

[image: Insert Page X of Y]

Or, if you want to create it manually, you can add the number of pages by using the NumPages Field Code.

```
Insert > Quick Parts > Field > NumPages
```

[image: Insert NumPages Field Code]

Comment: I later realized that I suggested the wrong Field Code for manually adding the number of pages. Subman pointed out the correct Field Code: SectionPages

Answer (score 1):

When editing the footer, choose page numbers -> format page numbers and then choose start from 1 in the lower part of the tab. The part of the doc you want to number has to be in a new section, but as I noticed you already did that.

[image]

Comment: Use this + subman's trick = Page X (page number in the section) of Y (total pages in the section) 
or
only this = Page X (page number in the section) of Y (total pages in the document)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is edit the formulae. Click on the page number (so you see a grey box) then right click and choose "Edit Codes"

You basically want to change it to - { =  { PAGE  } + 1  }

(or however you want)

[Read this page as it has helped me a great lot.](http://word.mvps.org/faQs/Numbering/PageNumbering.htm)