# Word Footer starting at Page 3 with PageNr 1

Tags: microsoft-word

Hi I have a Word 2003 Document and I want the Pagenumber-2 in the Footer starting at Page 3. I know how to add a custom footer for the first page and how to start numbering the pages at 0 but that way the second page still has a pagenumber in the footer.

I read [Page numbers in contents and footer](https://superuser.com/questions/39747/page-numbers-in-contents-and-footer) but it was not enough to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a "section break, new page" right before page 3.

The default is that the page numbers will continue from the previous section - whether you choose to display them or nbot.

Then set up the footers in the first section so that page numbers are **not shown**, and in the new section so that they **are shown**.

Comment: thx I was about to answer my own question and feeling bad about it :D You can reset the page numbering by removing the link to the previous page through a button and then set the pagenumbers to start at 1. That way I get seperate footers that start with 1 at page 3.

Comment: Hey ho! Well, thanks for the acceptance and upvote.